# Using Raphael.setViewBox zoom/pan to show entire contents of set / paper

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

My objective is to create some code that will show (no animation required) a set of objects as large as possible, in the center of the paper.

My current attempt gets the bounding box of a set of objects or paper and returns dimensions which is then used by `setViewBox`.  Unfortunately it just doesn't work and I have no idea why.

Here is my code

```
function GetContainingViewBoxFor(object)
{
var maxValues =  { x: 0, y: 0 };
var minValues =  { x: 0, y: 0 };

//Find max and min points
object.forEach(function (el) {
    if (el.data("background")) return;

    var bbox = el.getBBox();

    if (bbox.y < minValues.y) minValues.y = bbox.y;
    if (bbox.y2 < minValues.y) minValues.y = bbox.y2;

    if (bbox.y > maxValues.y) maxValues.y = bbox.y;
    if (bbox.y2 > maxValues.y) maxValues.y = bbox.y2;

    if (bbox.x < minValues.x) minValues.x = bbox.x;
    if (bbox.x2 < minValues.x) minValues.x = bbox.x2;

    if (bbox.x > maxValues.x) maxValues.x = bbox.x;
    if (bbox.x2 > maxValues.x) maxValues.x = bbox.x2;
});

//Padding
var padding = 50;
maxValues.x += padding;
minValues.x -= padding;
maxValues.y += padding;
minValues.y -= padding;

var w = maxValues.x - minValues.x;
var h = maxValues.y - minValues.y;

var cviewBox = {X:minValues.x - paper.width,Y:minValues.y,width:w,height:h};
return cviewBox;
}
```

And it is used like so:

```
var containingViewBox = GetContainingViewBoxFor(paper);

paper.setViewBox(containingViewBox.X, containingViewBox.Y, containingViewBox.width, containingViewBox.height, false);
```

Comment: In your previous question I wasn't aware that you needed the pan/zoom ability. I never have tryed the setViewBox() method, I'm using the RaphaelZPD library to do so. But the fiddle and the code that I gave to you get the scaling done... In this game I've made, you have a working example of the pan/zoom... and you can see how the map is centered and scaled in relation to the screen. www.disemo.com/mapas
The game is in spanish, just click on Juego Rapido, Suigiente.... Select a couple of continents, click on Jugar and explore the result of my code... if you need any help just let me know